# Management Activity API: Azure Active Directory events are not received

Tags: office-365, azure, auditing

I'm using Management API for audit logs and for the past 1 week I have been noticing that the events for Azure AD subscription are not received.
For example, **Delete User, Restore User** activities were being received previously but not any more.

In addition to this, I changed the license subscription for some the users of my tenant and I was expecting events like >>> **Set license properties, Change user license** but nothing in the stream and I have waited over 24 hours (considering the lag in the events as mentioned in the documentation)
Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: They just rolled out some major updates, can you log into your Office 365 Admin center and try running the same reports via the Compliance Center or see if they are available?

Comment: @EricAlexander Tried the unified audit logging feature and my activities aren't showing up.

Comment: You may want to raise a support ticket with support through the Office 365  Admin interface.